# Capturing input values onsubmit

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've got a separate js file to capture and validate input that's typed into the input boxes. However, I'm not having any luck with it. I've got another example from class that is working correctly but this one will not work.

validator.js

```
function validateInput() { 
  var firstName = document.forms["myForm"]["firstName"].value;
  if (firstName != NULL || firstName != "")
    return false;
  else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

And my createPerson.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/validator.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateInput()" action="createPerson.php" method="post">
  <input type="input" name="firstName" id="firstName">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

No matter what I do (I THINK) the javascript is failing, because if I just have return false; inside the js file, it will not send to createPerson.php. I'm assuming I'm capturing the value incorrectly, so I'm turning to you for some help.

Comment: Perhaps it's <input type="input".  That should probably be <input type="text"

Comment: Use/bind the form its "submit" event (google it) and return false when check fails. Learn jQuery, it's easier in all kind of ways. Besides, it is better to do the check server-side because your create person method is very easy to abuse. Also, I think you are trying to re-invent the wheel. Why not using a framework that handles this kind of problems for you.

Comment: @Erwinus It's for a class I'm taking and our prof said no jQuery (yet).

And durbnpoisn I have tried that as well to no such luck.

Comment: well, first of all, are you sure you are returning the proper thing? normally, if its empty you should return `false`, not `true`

Comment: I fixed it. It was my own logical errors. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please post an answer with the solution instead of fixing the error in the question.